# Code optimisation for reading files from App_data folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to open files from App_Data folder and i found this code snippet, Just want to know if this code is optimized.

I files can be of type .docx, doc, .pdf

```
try
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/File.txt");


            //string = Server.MapPath(strRequest); 
            System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/....";
                Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                Response.End();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
            }
        }


        catch (Exception rt)
        {
           // Response.Write(rt.Message);
        }
```

Or use this code snippet

```
FileStream MyFileStream;long FileSize;
string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v1.pdf");
MyFileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
FileSize = MyFileStream.Length;
byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize + 1];
MyFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)MyFileStream.Length);
MyFileStream.Close();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyReport.PDF");
Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
```

Please recommend which approach i should use. What i want simple is that user click on a link to open document. And this link is send to user by email.

**UPDATE**

I actually want to know if used object are closed properly and if this code in disposing in a proper way

Comment: Have you considered using a `StopWatch` class to time each code snippet? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

Comment: @JasonEvans,  I actually want to know if used object are closed properly and if this code in disposing in a properway

Comment: Ahhh OK, so not a performance question. Right, I'll have another look.

Answer (score 0):

The two points here that we need to compare is the [`HttpResponse.WriteFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyfzssz9.aspx) with the code

```
FileSize = MyFileStream.Length;
byte[] Buffer = new byte[(int)FileSize + 1];
MyFileStream.Read(Buffer, 0, (int)MyFileStream.Length);
MyFileStream.Close();
Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
```

I will suggest the `HttpResponse.WriteFile` because is doing the exactly same thing but with some more checks that is necessary. Also the above code is place the file first on memory, and this can be an issue on large files.

Here is the inside code of `HttpResponse.WriteFile`

```
public void WriteFile(string filename, bool readIntoMemory)
{
    if (filename == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("filename");
    }
    filename = this.GetNormalizedFilename(filename);
    FileStream f = null;
    try
    {
        f = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
        if (this.UsingHttpWriter)
        {
            long length = f.Length;
            if (length > 0L)
            {
                // this is false if you call the 
                // HttpResponse.WriteFile(string fileName) 
                if (readIntoMemory)
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) length];
                    int count = f.Read(buffer, 0, (int) length);
                    this._httpWriter.WriteBytes(buffer, 0, count);
                }
                else
                {
                    f.Close();
                    f = null;
                    this._httpWriter.WriteFile(filename, 0L, length);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.WriteStreamAsText(f, 0L, -1L);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (f != null)
        {
            f.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Also you use the `HttpResponse.WriteFile` is send the file without adding first on the memory the full file, that is very good because you avoid the extra memory fill in.

Now, if I was go to make the same code, I will send the file by break it on parts of limited buffer side.

Comment: It seems like advance thing. I am open to anything which will be more of a professional approach. Complete code example would be great.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker with one word, go with the `Response.WriteFile`